# Is there a way to convert days to years using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 columns named "deleted_at" (date the client canceled the service) and "birth_date" (of a client). I already transformed the string into date type using pd.to_datetime. Example:

> mydataframe.loc[:,'deleted_at'] =
> pd.to_datetime(mydataframe['deleted_at']).

I am trying to calculate the age of the client using:

> mydataframe [age] = (mydataframe['deleted_at'] -
> mydataframe['birth_date'])/365.25

The problem is this code is returning the date in days and I would like to receive in years. Example:

> [deleted_at] 2018-06-17 23:59:08 -
> [birth_date] 1966-01-25

Is returning: 52 days 09:27:43.101984942. Should return 52 years, x months, y days, or even just 52 years. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Side note: dividing by `365.25` is not the proper way to account for leap years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solution is much easier:

```
mydataframe[age] = (mydataframe['deleted_at'].dt.year - mydataframe['birth_date'].dt.year)
```

you can call day, week, month and year

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) from [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package (already installed with pandas)

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

cols = ['deleted_at', 'birth_date']
df['relativedelta'] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: relativedelta(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
```

Output:

| deleted_at | birth_date | relativedelta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-17 23:59:08 | 1966-01-25 00:00:00 | relativedelta(years=+52, months=+4, days=+23, hours=+23, minutes=+59, seconds=+8) |

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'deleted_at': [pd.Timestamp('2018-06-17 23:59:08')],
                   'birth_date': [pd.Timestamp('1966-01-25')]})
```